# C: struct timespec library

Tags: c, overloading

I'm trying to write a minor lib that would enable me to measure average time measured when using `struct timespec`. Since C doesn't allow operator overloading, I'm forced to build functions. I am aware that checks like `end_time < start_time` are not done, but I've left them out to achieve some kind of shortness in the code. The accuracy of the calculations is primary goal.

```
enum { NS_PER_SECOND = 1000000000L };
enum { MAX_NS = 999999999 };

// t1 --> start time
// t2 --> end time
// set t1 and t2 by:
//        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t1);
struct timespec get_timespec_diff(const struct timespec t1, const struct timespec t2)
{
    struct timespec t;

    t.tv_nsec = t2.tv_nsec - t1.tv_nsec;
    t.tv_sec  = t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec;

    if (t.tv_sec > 0 && t.tv_nsec < 0) {
        t.tv_nsec += NS_PER_SECOND;
        t.tv_sec--;
    } else if (t.tv_sec < 0 && t.tv_nsec > 0) {
        t.tv_nsec -= NS_PER_SECOND;
        t.tv_sec++;
    }

    return t;
}

struct timespec timespec_add(const struct timespec t1, const struct timespec t2) {

    unsigned int total_ns   = t1.tv_nsec + t2.tv_nsec;
    unsigned int total_s    = t1.tv_sec  + t2.tv_sec;

    while(total_ns > MAX_NS) {
        total_ns -= (unsigned)(MAX_NS + 1);
        total_s++;
    }

    struct timespec ret;
    ret.tv_sec  = total_s;
    ret.tv_nsec = total_ns;

    return ret;
}

struct timespec timespec_avg(const struct timespec t, const unsigned n) {

    struct timespec ret;
    ret.tv_sec  = 0;
    ret.tv_nsec = 0;

    unsigned int total_ns = t.tv_nsec + (t.tv_sec * (MAX_NS+1));
    unsigned int avg_ns = total_ns/n;

    while(avg_ns > MAX_NS) {
        ret.tv_sec++;
        avg_ns /= 10;
    }
    ret.tv_nsec = avg_ns;

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to `#include <time.h>` for `struct timespec` to be defined.

---

Why are `NS_PER_SECOND` and `MAX_NS` enum members?  There's no advantage compared to plain old `const long`.  I'm not sure why we need two constants anyway; the code that uses `MAX_NS` is simplified if we use `NS_PER_SECOND` instead:

```
long total_ns   = t1.tv_nsec + t2.tv_nsec;
time_t total_s  = t1.tv_sec  + t2.tv_sec;

while (total_ns >= NS_PER_SECOND) {
    total_ns -= NS_PER_SECOND;
    ++total_s;
}
```

(Note the use of the correct types in this version).

---

I think this logic is wrong:

```
if (t.tv_sec > 0 && t.tv_nsec < 0) {
    t.tv_nsec += NS_PER_SECOND;
    t.tv_sec--;
} else if (t.tv_sec < 0 && t.tv_nsec > 0) {
    t.tv_nsec -= NS_PER_SECOND;
    t.tv_sec++;
}
```

I'm reasonably sure that `tv_nsec` should always be positive, even when `tv_sec` is negative.  So we can simplify that to just:

```
if (t.tv_nsec < 0) {
    t.tv_nsec += NS_PER_SECOND;
    t.tv_sec--;
}
```

Note that the logic in `timespec_add()` already assumes positive `tv_nsec`.

---

This is highly susceptible to overflow:

```
unsigned int total_ns = t.tv_nsec + (t.tv_sec * (MAX_NS+1));
```

The whole reason we have `struct timespec` is that we might need to represent values outside the range of the integer types.  Probably better to use `divmod` to divide `tv_nsec` by `n`, and add the remainder to `nsec` before dividing - we need to be very careful here to avoid overflow.  Again, an unsigned type is inconsistent with other code.

## Modified code

Here's my version of these functions:

```
#include <time.h>

const long NS_PER_SECOND = 1000000000L;

struct timespec timespec_sub(const struct timespec t1, const struct timespec t2)
{
    struct timespec t;

    t.tv_nsec = t2.tv_nsec - t1.tv_nsec;
    t.tv_sec  = t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec;

    if (t.tv_nsec < 0) {
        t.tv_nsec += NS_PER_SECOND;
        t.tv_sec--;
    }
    return t;
}

struct timespec timespec_add(const struct timespec t1, const struct timespec t2)
{
    struct timespec t = { t1.tv_sec + t2.tv_sec, t1.tv_nsec + t2.tv_nsec };
    if (t.tv_nsec >= NS_PER_SECOND) {
        t.tv_nsec -= NS_PER_SECOND;
        t.tv_sec++;
    }
    return t;
}

struct timespec timespec_divide(struct timespec t, const int n)
{
    time_t remainder_secs = t.tv_sec % n;
    t.tv_sec /= n;
    t.tv_nsec /= n;
    t.tv_nsec +=
        remainder_secs * (NS_PER_SECOND / n) +
        remainder_secs * (NS_PER_SECOND % n) / n;

    while (t.tv_nsec >= NS_PER_SECOND) {
        t.tv_nsec -= NS_PER_SECOND;
        t.tv_sec++;
    }
    return t;
}
```

And a primitive unit-test:

```
int main(void)
{
    const struct timespec a = { 1, 905234817 };
    struct timespec a_2 = timespec_add(a, a);
    struct timespec a_4 = timespec_add(a_2, a_2);
    struct timespec a_5 = timespec_add(a_4, a);
    struct timespec z = timespec_sub(a, timespec_divide(a_5, 5));
    return z.tv_sec || z.tv_nsec;
}
```

You should expand on the testing, to prove correctness for the tricky cases where overflow could happen.

---

## Further simplification

We can separate out the code to normalise out-of-range nanoseconds into its own function:

```
struct timespec timespec_normalise(struct timespec t)
{
    t.tv_sec += t.tv_nsec / NS_PER_SECOND;
    if ((t.tv_nsec %= NS_PER_SECOND) < 0) {
        /* division rounds towards zero, since C99 */
        t.tv_nsec += NS_PER_SECOND;
        --t.tv_sec;
    }
    return t;
}
```

Then the functions can use that, to make them shorter and simpler:

```
struct timespec timespec_sub(const struct timespec t1, const struct timespec t2)
{
    struct timespec t = { t2.tv_nsec - t1.tv_nsec, t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec };
    return timespec_normalise(t);
}

struct timespec timespec_add(const struct timespec t1, const struct timespec t2)
{
    struct timespec t = { t1.tv_sec + t2.tv_sec, t1.tv_nsec + t2.tv_nsec };
    return timespec_normalise(t);
}

struct timespec timespec_divide(struct timespec t, const int n)
{
    time_t remainder_secs = t.tv_sec % n;
    t.tv_sec /= n;
    t.tv_nsec /= n;
    t.tv_nsec +=
        remainder_secs * (NS_PER_SECOND / n) +
        remainder_secs * (NS_PER_SECOND % n) / n;
    return timespec_normalise(t);
}
```

Because we have the unit tests, we have high confidence that we haven't affected the functionality here.

Comment: `timespec_divide()` has problems.  `time_t` may be floating point so `t.tv_sec % n` does not certainly compile.  `remainder_secs * (NS_PER_SECOND % n)` subject to integer overflow when `n > LONG_MAX/n`.  When `n < 0`, additional issues.

Comment: I had thought that `time_t` needed to be integer; forgotten that wasn't required.  Yes, the divide still has problems; thanks for showing that.  Unfortunately no time to fix that now (it's good to show how tricky this stuff can be!)

Comment: The problems with larger `n` could probably help inform some additional unit tests...

Answer (score 1):

**`time_t` assumptions, not specifications**

OP's code assumes 1) `time_t` is an integer type. It could be floating point. 2) `unsigned/int` are not 16-bit - they could be.

Writing portable time code is difficult due to #1. Rest of answer will assume #1.

***normal range***

The normal ranges are `.tv_sec >= 0` and `0 <= .tv_nsec <= 999999999`.  Useful is code does not rely on that too much.

**Overflow risk**

In `timespec_add()`, `t1.tv_sec + t2.tv_sec` risks overflow and thus *undefined behavior*.

`unsigned int total_ns = t1.tv_nsec + t2.tv_nsec;` can readily fail to provide correct results when `unsigned` is 16-bit - best to use `long`.

---

**Strange name**

`timespec_avg(const struct timespec t, const unsigned n)` looks more like a divide than an average of time.

Alternate suggestion:

```
#include <time.h>
#define NS_PER_SECOND 1000000000

// Averaging without overflow, even if `t1,t2` outside normal range
struct timespec timespec_avg(struct timespec t1, struct timespec t2) {
  struct timespec avg;
  int remainder = t1.tv_sec % 2 + t2.tv_sec % 2;
  avg.tv_sec = t1.tv_sec / 2 + t1.tv_sec / 2;
  avg.tv_nsec = t1.tv_nsec / 2 + t1.tv_nsec / 2 + (t1.tv_nsec % 2 + t1.tv_nsec % 2) / 2;
  avg.tv_sec += avg.tv_nsec / NS_PER_SECOND;
  avg.tv_nsec = avg.tv_nsec % NS_PER_SECOND + (NS_PER_SECOND / 2 * remainder);
  if (avg.tv_nsec >= NS_PER_SECOND) {
    avg.tv_nsec -= NS_PER_SECOND;
    avg.tv_sec++;
  } else if (avg.tv_nsec < 0) {
    avg.tv_nsec += NS_PER_SECOND;
    avg.tv_sec--;
  }
  return avg;
}
```